# AverageAsync throws exception when enumeration is empty

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

Using Entity Framework Core I have the following query:

```
var avgDuration = await projects.AverageAsync(x => x.Duration);
```

When the enumeration `projects` is empty I get the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements.
```

Is there a way to `AverageAsync` to not throw exception when enumeration as not elements.

Should not just return null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to `AverageAsync` to not throw exception when enumeration as not elements.
>
> Should not just return null?

`Average` and `AverageAsync` (as well as `Min`, `Max`) will return `null` on empty set when the value type is *nullable*. If it is not, just promote it to the corresponding nullable type using C# cast operator.

For instance, if in your sample the type of `x.Duration` is `int`, then use `int?` cast:

```
var avgDuration = await projects.AverageAsync(x => (int?)x.Duration);
```

And if you want to get 0 (zero) when the source set is empty, then simply apply `?? 0` to the result.

Comment: Wouldn't be better to use DefaultIfEmpty? Isn't that the purpose of it? Not sure ... I tried and at least it worked.

Comment: @MiguelMoura How about `x.Duration` expression when `x` is `null` (default)? `DefaultIfEmpty` is mainly for implementing left outer joins due to the lack of special LINQ operator.

Comment: In this case Duration is never null ... The problem is when projects enumeration is empty. Am I missing something from your question?

Comment: @MiguelMoura When you use `DefaultIfEmpty`, the variable `x` will be `null` when the original set is empty. So `x.Duration` will produce exception due to accessing `null` member.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve it ... Use DefaultIfEmpty:

```
var avgDuration = await projects.DefaultIfEmpty().AverageAsync(x => x.Duration);
```